# Getting UART from my MCU to PC

Tags: usb, uart

I am working on a LPC4088 microcontroller and I am using [this board](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/EA-LPC4088/) which has UART3, UART4 and HDK UART0 pins available on the expansion connector. Could I use [this kind of circuit](http://www.ebay.com/itm/FT232RL-3-3V-5-5V-FTDI-USB-to-TTL-Serial-Adapter-Module-for-Arduino-Mini-Port-/141724029351?hash=item20ff6911a7:g:6qUAAOSw3ydVrhnF) to listen to my UART on my PC? What about USB pins D+, D-? Would it be hard to use those to communicate with my PC?

Listenning to my UART over "USB Host Interface" (upwards type A USB next to ethernet interface) on my board is probably the hard way to go?

I am just curious on how to achieve this as simple as possible, but I am bugged by the fact that I'll probably have to buy another circuit... Well I'll do it if this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit you're showing is usefull to get your 3V3 USB signal from the board and convert it to a 5V USB signal for your computer.

You can check for come board to connect the Rx/Tx pins of UARTs to your computer to communicate both ways with the board.

Btw, using USB pins could be a real pain if you don't have some library with easy functions to use. UART stuff is more accessible.

Comment: Yeah that's what I had in mind - USB is allways painfull because of libraries. So I will first choose the easiest choice (I will buy some sort of a FTDI board). I also found this library which is for all NXP microcontrollers: https://www.lpcware.com/content/project/nxpusblib

Comment: FTDI boards are easy to use and there is maaaaany of them. But if you're not used to serial communication, UART may be an easy begining.

Comment: Well I ordered 6 different circuits from EBay and now have to wait untill they arrive. Is there any way to indicate with a LED that I am transmitting over UART? How would I connect an LED to my UART pins to indicate this while I am waiting for the package?

Comment: Maybe on the board you'll use you have a led on both Tx and Rx, otherwise, you can programmatically map a LED to it, I don't know how you'll code it.